# how to Change the text of the Google translate

Tags: google-translate

i want to Change the text of select language.

[image]

I tried for a long time, but you can't change it.

I tried the following code

```
$("#google_translate_element span").eq(1).text("Hello");
```

```
<!-- Google Translate Element begin -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,es,pl,pt,zh-CN,zh-TW,ar,so,ru,hy,ko,vi',
            layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Comment: what exactly you wanna do ?

Comment: I think the text "Select Language" in that widget should be changed to something else, like "Hello"

Comment: i want to Change the default text of select language to custom my text.